# Update Android Studio-

Tags: android

I installed some useful Android SDK tools, but now I got this problem. Can somebody tell me where can I find "Update & Restart"? Or which is another way of getting rid of this problem? Thanks :D

> Rendering Problems
>
> This version of the rendering library is more
>   recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android
>   Studio (Details)

Answer (score 1):

> where can I find "Update & Restart"?

These are 2 seperate actions.

To update, go to `Help > Check for update` in the top bar

To restart, just close the program and start it again